# Read client certificate subject in openresty

Tags: nginx, ssl, lua, openssl, openresty

I am a newb in lua.

I am using the openresty/openresty:1.21.4.1-3-alpine-fat image.

The client sends its certificate in the request.

I need to read the subject of the certificate to implement some business logic but I can't seem to be able to find how to read the certificate.
I need the equivalent(or better) of the openssl command: `openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem`

What I tried:

```lua
content_by_lua_block {
            local ssl = require "ngx.ssl"
            local cjson = require "cjson"
            local x509 = require "resty.openssl.x509"
            local cert = ngx.var.ssl_client_cert;
            local json = {certificate = cert}
            local x509_cert, err = ssl.parse_pem_cert(cert)
            ngx.say(x509_cert)
        }
```

This gives me a `PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed`

Next thing I tried was

```lua
        content_by_lua_block {
            local ssl = require "ngx.ssl"
            local cjson = require "cjson"
            local x509 = require "resty.openssl.x509"
            local cert = ngx.var.ssl_client_cert;
            local json = {certificate = cert}
            local x509_cert, err = x509.new(cert, PEM) 
            ngx.log(ngx.INFO,"certificate parse:", x509_cert)
            ngx.log(ngx.INFO,"error: ", err)
            -- local issuer = x509.read(cert)
            ngx.say(cjson.encode(json))
            ngx.say(x509_cert)
        }
```

But this gave me a `x509.new: asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error` which suggests certificate coruption.

So I used the openssl used by resty to run `openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem` and it worked.

At this point I have exhausted all the documentation suggestions on this issue and can't find any lead on the interent. So your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet:

> ```
>        local x509_cert, err = ssl.parse_pem_cert(cert)
>        ngx.say(x509_cert)
> ```

`parse_pem_cert` just loads certificate into luajit memory in cdata format. It is AFAIK only intended to use it with `set_cert` and you cannot it just print because it's pointer to that memory block.
https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/ssl.md#parse_pem_cert

However, you you were closer with your second snippet, try this:

> ```
> local ngx_client_cert_raw = ngx.var.ssl_client_raw_cert
> local x509 = require "resty.openssl.x509"
> local x509_client_cert = x509.new(ngx_client_cert_raw, PEM)
> local x509_client_cert_subject = client_cert:get_subject_name()
> ngx.say(x509_client_cert_subject:tostring())
> ```

More info here https://github.com/fffonion/lua-resty-openssl#x509get_-x509set_.